# Update rows of a table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a few tables as follows:-

Projects

```
ProjectId Status
1         Completed
2         Completed
3         In Progress
4         In Progress
```

Contracts

```
ContractId Status
1          In Progress
2          In Progress
3          In Progress
4          In Progress
```

ProjectContracts

```
ContractId ProjectId
1          1
1          2
2          3
3          4
```

ProjectContracts

```
ContractId ProjectId
1          1
1          2
2          3
3          4
```

I want to create an update script that updates all the contracts status as completed whose projects status are completed.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: So what have you tried? and what goes wrong? can we see some code?

Comment: @did the below answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that is what you are looking for. correct me if we are not in the same page in terms of the logic behind your requirements.

```
  UPDATE   contract c
  SET      c.status=(SELECT p.status
  FROM     projects p
  WHERE    c.projectId = p.projectid AND p.status = 'completed');
```